"Less known is that 48% of them are left handed" — "Less known" is put in front. Is this inversion possible because "less" has a negative connotation?
wordreference.com:
(1) Everyone knows that China has a large population, less known is that 48% of them are left handed, lesser known is that 45% of them play the violin and least known is the fact that 2,000,000 Chinese can explain Einstein's theory.
Is this an example of inversion?
If not, then how to explain the adjective phrases "less known", "lesser known" and "least known" are fronted?
If it is, is this inversion possible only because the words "less", "lesser" and "least" have a negative connotation?

my variant (without the inversion):
(2) Everyone knows that China has a large population, that 48% of them are left handed is less known, that 45% of them play the violin is lesser known and the fact that 2,000,000 Chinese can explain Einstein's theory is least known.
Is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, since versions without inversion are normally more common, then (2) is more common than (1), right?

Can I say a similar sentence containing an inversion like in (1) but without a negative connotation?
For example:
(3) Few people know that 48% of China are left handed, far better known is that it has a large population.
Is the inversion in (3) correct?
If it is, then since there is not a negative connotation, why is the inversion in (3) possible?

What is 'Einstein's theorem'?

It's just a shift in emphasis. It doesn't matter whether the connotation is positive or negative. The main emphasis of a sentence or clause generally lands at the end, so we lead with the context ("not many people know this, which is why you might want to hear it…") and end with the part we actually want to focus on, the fact itself.
If we inverted all those clauses, it would still be valid English, but it would shift the primary focus toward comparing how well-known each fact is, perhaps taking for granted that the facts themselves are already known to the reader.
For the record, I don't think the person on that forum is actually correct about the difference between less and lesser (nor, obviously, about China).

You wrote: "we ... end with the part we actually want to focus on". Doesn't extraposition do this role? That is, if we want to put the that-clause to the end to focus on it, isn't it better to use extraposition for this purpose? What is the difference between "It is less known that 48% of them are left handed" and "Less known is that 48% of them are left handed" ? Thanks.

You don't need to use extraposition. There's more than one valid way to express things in any language. Extraposition requires extra words and would make the structure longer, less easy to parse, and more ungainly.
